# Multi-line strings with indentation as input to C++ logging macros

Tags: ros, c++, logging

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How can I input a multi-line string to one of the C++ logging functions and have it properly ignore the white space? Here's an example:

```
ROS_INFO("Cost error: %d = \
        (Current: %u - Initial: %u)",
        error_cost, cost, cost_init);
```

What ends up being printed is a single line (desirable) but with a bunch of spaces (undesirable):

```
Cost error: 0 =                       (Current: 88 - Initial: 88)
```

Reading this (http://stackoverflow.com/a/1135862/2653356) I realized that the backslash takes care of the new line but not the indentation. Is there a better way? (I'd rather not define the string beforehand and then pass a variable to `ROS_INFO` if I can avoid it.)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/233798/multi-line-strings-with-indentation-as-input-to-c++-logging-macros/) by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1788 on 2016-05-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

C/C++ implicitly joins string literals that are adjacent, so you can do:

```
ROS_INFO("Cost error: %d = "
         "(Current: %u - Initial: %u)",
         error_cost, cost, cost_init);
```

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-05-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1